# Calling a Python Function in C++

Tags: python, c++

I have been struggling to get a simple set of code to work and was curious if anyone else has run into this issue:

**TestComponent.cpp**

```
#include <Python.h>

int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();

    PyObject* moduleString = PyUnicode_FromString("test");
    PyObject* module = PyImport_Import(moduleString);
    if (!module) {
        PyErr_Print();
        Py_Finalize();
        return 1;
    }

    PyObject* dict = PyModule_GetDict(module);
    PyObject* func = PyDict_GetItemString(dict, "python_test");

    if (func && PyCallable_Check(func)) {
        PyObject_CallObject(func, nullptr);
    }

    Py_Finalize();
}
```

**test.py**

```
# Python Test
def python_test():
    print("Python Test")
```

**moduleString**, **module**, and **dict** all get initialized correctly, but no matter what I do, **func** always gets initialized as NULL and the if-statement doesn't go through. Any suggestions?

[Here is the debbuger information for dict, if it helps.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivSrw.png)

---

I tried:

- Different function names and contents for the Python script
- Different locations for the Python script
- Different methods of calling the Python script (like doing PyObject_GetAttrString(module, "python_test")

Comment: When you say that `dict` is initialised correctly, how did you verify its correctness?  Can you include your test code that prints its keys?

Comment: btw is there a typo in your code? `PyModule_GetDict(dict)` references `dict` before it is defined.

Comment: @TobySpeight, I just verified it since it was not initialized as nullptr. I added the debugger information into the post.

Comment: @quamrana, yes, it was a typo - it's correct in the actual code.

Comment: It works for me with `$PWD` at the front of my `PYTHONPATH`.  I used a different name than `test` - are you sure you're picking up the correct `test` module?

Comment: @TobySpeight, that honestly might've been it? I've been fumbling around and I changed the module name and the sys path and that seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite likely that you have loaded the wrong `test` module.  We can add some diagnostic output to show the content of the module we loaded:

```
#include <cstdio>
```

```
    PyObject* dict = PyModule_GetDict(module);
    PyObject_Print(module, stdout, 0); std::puts("");
    PyObject_Print(PyDict_Keys(dict), stdout, 0); std::puts("");
```

When I run this with `PYTHONPATH` not set in the environment, I get the content of Python's `test` module:

```
<module 'test' from '/usr/lib/python3.11/test/__init__.py'>
['__name__', '__doc__', '__package__', '__loader__', '__spec__', '__path__', '__file__', '__cached__', '__builtins__']
```

When I run it with `PYTHONPATH` set to `.`, I see the local `test.py`:

```
<module 'test' from '/home/■■■■■■■/test.py'>
['__name__', '__doc__', '__package__', '__loader__', '__spec__', '__file__', '__cached__', '__builtins__', 'python_test']
Python Test
```

In the latter case, `python_test` is one of the keys, and the function is called.